# Can anybody please check my working on showing the uniform convergence of $f_n$ to $f$?

Tags: metric-spaces, uniform-convergence

Let $(X,d)$ and $(Y,\rho)$ be metric spaces, $X$ compact, and suppose $f:X\to Y$ and $f_n:X\to Y$ are continuous functions such that $\rho(f_n(x),f(x))$ **decreases** to 0 as $n\to\infty$ for each $x\in X$. Prove that $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$.

I could start doing this problem by writing some definitions:

Since $X$ is compact, then every sequence from $X$ has a subsequence which converges to an element of $X$. Since $f$ and $f_n$ are continuous, then $Y$ is also compact. We need to show that for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N$ such that $n\geq N\implies\rho(f_n(x),f(x))<\epsilon,\forall x\in X$.

Some of my doubts are:

Does the meaning of the sentence $\rho(f_n(x),f(x))$ decreases to $0$ as $n\to\infty$ for each $x\in X$ means $\rho(f_n(x),f(x))\to0$ as $n\to\infty$ for each $x\in X$?

If yes, then from definition of limit we have for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N$ such that $n\geq N\implies|\rho(f_n(x),f(x))-0|=|\rho(f_n(x),f(x))|=\rho(f_n(x),f(x))<\epsilon$. Then we are done.

Am I correct? I am not sure though.

Also I am not sure if we can use Dini's Theorem, if we can, how can we use it?

Could anybody please give some help? Thanks so much.

Comment: "$\rho(f_n(x),f(x))$ decreases to $0$" means more than $\rho(f_n(x),f(x)) \to 0$, additionally $\rho(f_{n+1}(x),f(x)) \leqslant \rho(f_n(x),f(x))$. Your argument however is insufficient, because the $N$ you chose depends on $x$; given $\varepsilon > 0$, for every $x\in X$, there is an $N(x,\varepsilon)$ such that $\rho(f_n(x),f(x)) < \varepsilon$ for all $n \geqslant N(x,\varepsilon)$. You need to find an $N(\varepsilon)$ that works for all $x$ simultaneously. You can mimic the proof of Dini's theorem, or look at the sequence $(g_n)$ where $g_n(x) = \rho(f_n(x),f(x))$.

Comment: @user71346: I was about to leave a comment to a question you deleted. A common rounding convention, which I think has been adopted as standard by IEEE, is that to round when we have a $5$ we round to the *even* digit. So $0.125$, rounded to $2$ places, is $0.12$, while $0.135$, rounded to $2$ places, is $0.14$.